# actual code for xferring javascript variable to post variable

Tags: javascript, php, post, save, onchange

I have looked at this site for three days. I admit I am new to using javascript. But I have used the many different solutions offered and none have worked. Please help.

I am trying to do something that should be simple: save a user choice of country from a dropdown box on an html5 page to a hidden post variable (using javascript onchange.) That is used in a post array on the same form for a php operation that sends the input to a mysql database. This is my code:

The hidden post variable doesn't update. From there I can't test the code logic. But my onchange code came from this site and is suppose to work.

**References:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../../js/jquery-2.1.4.min_prod.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../../js/respond.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

**form information:**

```
<form name="form1"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" />
</form>
```

**form element**

```
$query="SELECT * from  country ";
$query=$query."ORDER BY country asc";
$data = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
//or die('could not connect to db:'. mysqli_connect_error() );
mysqli_error($conn);
If ($data) {
echo '<select id="country"  onchange="send_name(this)">';
echo '<option value="204">United States</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
echo '<option  value="'.$row['country_id'].'">'.$row['country'].'</option>';
}//while
echo '</select>';
}//if
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<input type="hidden" id="c_php_value" name="c_php_value" value="">
```

**Javascript**

```
function send_name(selectObjectI) {
        var value = selectObjectI.value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/php/protected/form_addnews.php",
            data:{c_php_value: value}

        });
```

**Post Submit Code**

```
$country_id1 = trim($_POST['c_php_value']);
```

Comment: You're never changing or reading the value of the hidden field - what do you expect it to do? You can't use the value in `$_POST` either, since you're not sending a JSON value as the value of a key in the POST. Is there _any_ reason why it should be JSON, and not just a regular POST?

Comment: is not this statment suppose to do this? $.post("form_addnews.php", JSON.stringify({c_php_value: value}));

Comment: okay. I see from my javascript debugging[thanks, utube] that my onchange is working. And like he said above, the value is not transferred to the hidden post object. but if the json statement doesn't do this what does? thanks

Comment: I have discovered that I am missing double quotes from my json statement. it should be "c_php_value". Apparently this is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a coder on utube, speaking german I might add, I discovered I don't need javascript, ajax or anything complicated to accomplish what I am trying to do.

I simply needed to do the following:

(1) Add a name="" to the dynamically created SELECT flag(name="country_id2").

(2) user chooses input with drop down box created.

(3) gather the $_POST after the form submit is set. 
($country_id = $_POST['country_id2'])

```
$data = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
//or die('could not connect to db:'. mysqli_connect_error() );
mysqli_error($conn);
If ($data) {
    echo '<select name="country_id2" id="country_id2">';
    echo '<option value="204">United States</option>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
       echo '<option     value="'.$row['country_id'].'">'.$row['country'].'</option>';
    }//while
    echo '</select>';
}//if
mysqli_close($conn);
```